# Tiling planar integer lattice by finite point sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, tiling

I am interested in the following question.

Are there nice characterizations of the finite sets $S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ that tile $ \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ by translations (i.e.  $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ can be written as a disjoint of some translates of $S$)?

If nothing is known in general, is there anything known for some special family of interesting point sets, e.g. the convex hull of $S$ is a regular (or general) convex polygon, or points in $S$ consists of the vertices/boundary-points of a regular convex polygon?

Comment: The only regular polygons with vertices in $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ are squares.

Answer (score 5):

Every such $S$ has a periodic tiling, in which finitely many disjoint copies form a set with one representative for each translate of some discrete lattice $L$ - see [Bhattacharya 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05738) or [Greenfeld and Tao 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.03254). If $S$ is edge-connected, one can further guarantee that $S$ itself (rather than a finite number of copies) has a lattice tiling - see [Wijshoff and van Leeuwen 1984](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995884800078) - in which case the characterization is more concrete, as every such $S$ is given by the construction of picking a lattice and selecting a representative from each of its translates (and the decision problem is fairly computationally straightforward, taking time quadratic in the length of the boundary word).

For an example of a disconnected $S$ that cannot form a lattice tiling, consider $\{(0,0),(2,0)\}$; it requires two copies to form a patch that tiles by lattice translation.

I'm not sure you'll be able to get much more than this. The structure of tiling problems in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ even in the single-tile case is in general difficult, and for sufficiently high $d$ loses the periodicity condition as recently shown in Greenfeld and Tao 2022 - see [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2022/09/19/a-counterexample-to-the-periodic-tiling-conjecture/) blog post. And with more than one tile, the problem is known to become undecidable - for sufficiently high $d$ with two tiles, and already in two dimensions with $11$ tiles as shown in [Ollinger 2008](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00335781/document).

Comment: Even the one-dimensional finite problem of determining all the sets that tile a given cyclic group ${\bf Z}/N{\bf Z}$ is difficult; the main conjecture in this area is the Coven-Meyerowitz conjecture https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1670646 which remains open in general, though has been some recent progress by Laba and Londner, see e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.11809

Comment: Surely $S=\{\langle 0,0\rangle, \langle 1,0\rangle, \langle 3,0\rangle\}$ can't tile $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ by translation? If it could then $\{0, 1, 3\}$ would translate $\mathbb{Z}$ by translation and this is clearly impossible.

Comment: "The structure of tiling problems in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ even in the single-tile case is in general difficult, and undecidable for sufficiently high $d$ as recently shown in Greenfeld and Tao 2022 - see this blog post." is this really claimed by Greenfeld-Tao? I thought they have is a single aperiodic (singleton) tileset.

Comment: They explicitly say they don't address decidability issues, so hard to say whether they know how to get undecidability, but it does not look like they have a general "monotilification result" that turns anything into a single tile, and aperiodicity doesn't directly imply undecidability. Well, I see that @TerryTao has commented above already, maybe they know more than me.

Comment: (Indeed there is no general "monotilification result" in the sense that there are SFTs that are far from being conjugate to the set of tilings with a single tile, e.g. because single tile SFTs have deterministic directions and zero entropy. Of course neither of those things prevents undecidability.)

Comment: Our methods are currently only able to demonstrate aperiodicity in high dimensions for tiling with one tile, and undecidability in high dimensions for the problem of tiling with two tiles.  It seems reasonable to conjecture though that the problem of tiling with one tile is also undecidable in high dimensions.

Comment: @VilleSalo: Ah, you're correct - I missed the use of two tiles in the construction. I've edited the original answer.